# I am trying to understand how variables are assigned in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to change the text on this application I am developing currently. It currently says "Training resources" and I want to capitalize it to "Training Resources". When I go into the Flutter Inspector and click into the text, I find that it is called here as "title".

```
    title: Text(
      title,
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    ),
```

I then go to where "title" is being assigned as a variable and find this.

```
  title = widget.data!.title;
```

I am not sure what to do next. My best guess is to look for how widget is being built, but I don't know where to start looking. Any suggestions?

EDIT:

[Picture of the screen with "Training resources" as the title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Mlow.png)

[Picture of the "Training resources" text on a button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wpGL.png)

My end goal is to make this say "Training Resources" (just capitalize the 'R'). I cannot find where this "title" variable is called as a string though. My understanding of widgets in Flutter is limited.

Comment: `Text` is just a class instance, and `title` is a property. what's your final goal?

Comment: You need to find the current widget use cases.

Comment: Why wouldn't you fix the string at its source?

Comment: @jamesdlin That is what I am trying to find. So far I have only found   title = widget.data!.title; How do I dive deeper?

Comment: Search your source tree for the string "Training resources".  Learn how to use tools such as `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a string extension to capitalize the first letter of each word in the sentence

```
extension StringExtension on String {
  /// convert input string to string with capital letter of each word format
  /// i.e  this is test => This Is Test
  String get toCapitalizeFirstofEach {
    return split(" ").map((str) {
      return str.toSentence;
    }).join(" ");
  }

    /// convert input string to sentence format
    /// i.e this is test => This is test
    String get toSentence => length <= 1
        ? '$toLowerCase()'
        : '${this[0].toUpperCase()}${substring(1)}';
}
```

Then use it in any strings as

```
title: Text(
  title.toCapitalizeFirstofEach,
  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
),
```